# Database Queries Optimization with new WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, multisite, shortcode, optimization

I’m building (mostly with a self-teaching purpose) a simple plugin to query posts from another blog on a MS network via a shortcode (like [network-posts blogs=”8" layout=”grid” columns=”3"]), but I’m running into some performance issues/doubts.

**Here's the issue:**

To my understanding (and maybe I’m wrong), when creating and looping through a `new WP_Query`, only 1 new query should be executed on the database.

When I use the shortcode (without switching to another blog), 7 new database queries are added.

When I switch to another blog (just 1 switch), the additional queries become 32.

The additional queries are called by `update_meta_cache()` and `WP_Post::get_instance()`

and comes in the form of an handful of selects:

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value
FROM wp_11_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN (109)
ORDER BY meta_id ASC
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_11_posts
WHERE ID = 109
LIMIT 1
```

When switching to another blog, this two queries are duplicated for each post that's being loaded.

Is there a way to reduce the number of database queries?

The plugin is on github and this is the link to a simplified branch that I’m using for debugging purposes:
https://github.com/langhenet/display-network-posts/tree/debug
Here `switch_to_blog()` is commented in the php code, but you can activate it by uncommenting line 40 and 64.

EDIT: the plugin has just ~70 lines of code distributed over two files. I didn't paste the code here because I thought it would have been more readable on github.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the caching if you set `update_post_meta_cache` and `update_post_term_cache` to `false` while setting the `WP_Query` arguments.

When caching is disabled the data will be requested from the database only on demand.

You can check my post in [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226960/why-query-posts-isnt-marked-as-deprecated/248955#248955).
If you need more info just let me know.

Comment: thank you for your answer :-) I've tried to add `'update_post_meta_cache' => false`
     ` 'update_post_term_cache' => false` as WP_Query arguments, **but it's adding 7 more database queries**. Now I'm going to read your whole post and try to understand what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: other 7 may be related to some WordPress cronjobs or so.

Comment: I've read the your post (which was very interesting!). I also turned off Wp Cron, just to be sure and update_post_meta_cache still adds 7 queries to the database. I'm on a minimal setup (standard 2016 theme and no other plugin)... so I can't really understand why it's happening

Comment: Go ahead and share these queries if possible. Some database queries are to load the options table. This table is something like **persona grata**.